# Erro ao inserir Imagem no Readme.md no bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

Não consigo inserir a imagem dentro do **readme.dm no bitbucket**

**Código:**

```
    **## Modelo Relacional**
   ![ER Pessoas ](https://bitbucket.org/xxxx/api-yyyy/public/doc1.2/API yyyy 
   1.2/BPM/1.2/pessoas.png)
```

Comment: Não seria `readme.md`?

Answer (score 1):

Alguns possíveis pontos problemáticos que eu vi na sua questão, mas que talvez não signifiquem nada:

- extensão trocada; o sistema espera encontrar `.md` para [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown), não `.dm`
- URL com espaços, precisaria verificar se a URL é válida de qualquer sorte
- <strike>texto colado na marcação de subtítulo; normalmente costumo deixar com uma linha em branco para evitar confusão</strike>

Aqui no SOpt (e em demais sites da SE) usamos Markdown exaustivamente nas perguntas e respostas. Não é o mesmo Markdown do Bitbucket, mas é próximo o suficiente. Eu fiz [este teste seguinte no chiqueirinho de formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6492/64969).

Nos meus testes, eu descartei o terceiro item, mas sabe-se lá se no Bitbucket ele interpreta diferente, vou deixar riscado apenas para consulta por neura